# Is there a way to compare 2 elements of array of type char initialized with int?

Tags: c++, character

I'm having a program to allow a user to enter 12 elements of type char initialized with the characters that form, eg "991231066245" and I would like to compare whether the 3rd element and 4 element is equal to 12.

For example:

```
char UserInput[20];

cout << "user input: ";
cin >> UserInput; //eg: 991231066245

//compare 

int a = atoi(UserInput[2] + UserInput[3]); //something like this

if(a == 12){
 cout << "yes";
}
```

But I able to get UserInput[0] & UserInput[1] by using UserInput[2]=\0
then user atoi(UserInput) to compare 
If I add UserInput[4] = \0 then i will get 4 element so want to ask that is there any way to do? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
if (UserInput[2] == '1' && UserInput[3] == '2')
{
  std::cout << "yes\n";
}
```

If you have to convert to `int`, use `std::string` instead of `char*`, then it is very easy:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string UserInput{ "991231066245" };

    int a{ std::stoi(UserInput.substr(2, 2)) };

    std::cout << a << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
12
```

Comment: yes, it is possible and actually the 12 digits stand for my country identical number which the front 6 digit stands for YYMMDD and I want to do validation to make sure that the month is not more than 12 and less than 1 and also to validate the date too so it will not efficient if the code written in that way. Thank you but is there any more efficient way?

Comment: @N.Tec "_I want to do validation to make sure that the month is not more than 12 and less than 1_" - if you're doing id number validation, is that really what you should be checking? Doesn't your id number come with a checksum digit?